# Javascript list filter not work as expect

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to find the object's key that matches a specific value, but I only get an empty array, even though I'm sure that there is an object that matches the value. What am I doing wrong?

```
const list = this.myList.filter((item) => {
      return item.key === key
    })
```

here is my sample data:

```
let list = [{"key":"-NJdLxqKEJpDE_7zkmF9","createTime":1671436164193,"lastUpdate":1671436164193,"roomHost":"test@test.com","roomId":25930,"roomMembers":["test@test.com"],"roomName":"Test","todo":[{"addUser":"test@test.com","lastUpdate":1671436158447,"taskName":"1"},{"addUser":"test@test.com","lastUpdate":1671436159985,"taskName":"2"}]}]
```

and the key is '-NJdLxqKEJpDE_7zkmF9'
I have tried following code, and I still get a empty array. I think the problem might be on the string value?

```
let list = [{"key":"-NJdLxqKEJpDE_7zkmF9","createTime":1671436164193,"lastUpdate":1671436164193,"roomHost":"test@test.com","roomId":25930,"roomMembers":["test@test.com"],"roomName":"Test","todo":[{"addUser":"test@test.com","lastUpdate":1671436158447,"taskName":"1"},{"addUser":"test@test.com","lastUpdate":1671436159985,"taskName":"2"}]}]

let newList = list.filter((item)=>{
    item.key === '-NJdLxqKEJpDE_7zkmF9'
})
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code. You can use `Stack Snippets`. If you just want to find one value you can use `find` array method.

Comment: since you asked what you are doing wrong, the answer is not the code itself. You probably mistaken the `key` value or your didn't set it (being the value you are looking for in the array of objects). Or maybe the `myList` doesn't have the value expected (an array of objects each one having the property `key`).

Answer (score 1):

This is going to drive you nuts until you spot the simple mistake because you start with the correct code in the first box.

Your code:

```js
let list = [{"key":"-NJdLxqKEJpDE_7zkmF9","createTime":1671436164193,"lastUpdate":1671436164193,"roomHost":"test@test.com","roomId":25930,"roomMembers":["test@test.com"],"roomName":"Test","todo":[{"addUser":"test@test.com","lastUpdate":1671436158447,"taskName":"1"},{"addUser":"test@test.com","lastUpdate":1671436159985,"taskName":"2"}]}]

let newList = list.filter((item)=>{
    item.key === '-NJdLxqKEJpDE_7zkmF9'
    // return undefined (or filter everything)
})
```

Return that `item.key` check:

```js
let list = [{"key":"-NJdLxqKEJpDE_7zkmF9","createTime":1671436164193,"lastUpdate":1671436164193,"roomHost":"test@test.com","roomId":25930,"roomMembers":["test@test.com"],"roomName":"Test","todo":[{"addUser":"test@test.com","lastUpdate":1671436158447,"taskName":"1"},{"addUser":"test@test.com","lastUpdate":1671436159985,"taskName":"2"}]}]

let newList = list.filter((item)=> {
    // this will return true on match and include the item in the result
    return item.key === '-NJdLxqKEJpDE_7zkmF9'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need the return statement. You haven't specified exactly what you need to filter out.
Here is how you filter

```
 list = [
       {
         id:1,
         num:20
        },
        {
         id:2,
         num:22
        }
        ]
        

              const l =this.list.filter((item)=> item.id ==2)

      console.log(l)
```

Here the value of l would be 2

Comment: No, that's wrong; the fact that the OQ is lacking a piece of code example for his `list` its only safe to guess no `key` matches an element in his `list` array, hence why it's returning an *empty array*.

Then you said "You do not really need the return statement", which is wrong; it won't work without returning anything, you yourself are returning a value using *arrow function*'s shorthand way.

Comment: He is using an arrow function and return that why I said he doesnt need the return word